# Autocomplete Kendo Control I don't want to show "No Data found" when no matching records

Tags: angular, kendo-autocomplete

I have a autocomplete kendo control which I use with Angular, its working as expected but I don't want to show the "NO DATA FOUND" list when there are no records match the text that the user enter.

I find the option k-no-data-template but this set the template in case no data was found.

Basically I want to show the list only if there are match results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
noDataTemplate: ''
```

for example

```
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
   dataSource: [
     { id: 1, city: "Bangalore" },
     { id: 2, city: "Pune" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "city",
  noDataTemplate: ''
});
```

So here, **No Data found** message won't come and even if you want to customize it put then:

```
noDataTemplate: 'customized message'  // if you want to show your custom message to user
```

Hope it work for you.

Comment: If you are using Angular you can seet the option k-no-data-template="''"

Comment: Simple and effective suggestion :) didn't think of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option k-no-data-template="''"

Answer (score 0):

You can set this globally by css/sass:

```
.k-nodata
  *
    display: none
  &:after
    content: 'your custom text'
```